# Lector de JSON no funciona

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo este código:

```
    QProcess process;
process.start("powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://3ds.titlekeys.gq/json_enc -OutFile titles.json");
process.waitForFinished();
if (QFile::exists("titles.json"))
{
    QString content;
    QFile file("titles.json");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    content = file.readAll();
    file.close();
    QJsonDocument json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(content.toUtf8());
    QJsonObject list = json.object();
    QStringList jsontitles = list.keys();
    for (QString title : jsontitles)
    {
        QJsonObject title_data = list[title].toObject();
        QString gm9title = title_data["titleID"].toString();
        if (title_data["name"].toString() != "")
        {
            gm9title += " ";
            gm9title.append(title_data["name"].toString());
        }
        if (title_data["serial"].toString() != "")
        {
            gm9title += " ";
            gm9title += title_data["serial"].toString();
        }
        if (title_data["region"].toString() != "")
        {
            gm9title += " ";
            gm9title += title_data["region"].toString();
        }
        ui->listWidget->addItem(gm9title);
        titles.push_back(gm9title);
    }
}
```

Pero mi lista está vacía...

Comment: Se genera titles.json  en tu pc?

Comment: se descarga el archivo antes de abrirlo

Comment: Mi duda es que si entra al `if (QFile::exists("titles.json"))`?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que ingresa al `if (QFile::exists("titles.json"))`, el problema es causado porque tu tienes un array de objetos:

```
[{
    "titleID": "0004000e000edf00",
    "serial": "CTR-U-AXCE",
    "encTitleKey": "8b54088da074d78994d558868f5742aa",
    "name": "Super Smash Bros.\u2122 Update Ver. 1.1.6",
    "region": "USA",
    "size": 344718180
}, {
    "titleID": "00040000000d7e00",
    "serial": "CTR-N-JNUP",
    "encTitleKey": "27107daf63011babf7ba603397b1889d",
    "name": "Steel Diver\u2122: Sub Wars",
    "region": "EUR",
    "size": 205773668
[...]
```

Por lo que debes usar el metodo array(), despues la tarea es similar al codigo inicial:

```
if (QFile::exists("titles.json"))
{   
    QString content;
    QFile file("titles.json");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    content = file.readAll();
    file.close();
    QJsonDocument json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(content.toUtf8());
    const QStringList keys{"name", "serial", "region"};
    QString gm9title;

    for(const QJsonValue &value : json.array()){
        if(value.isObject()){
            QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
            gm9title =obj["titleID"].toString();
            for(const QString &key: keys){
                gm9title += obj[key].toString().isEmpty() ? "" : " "+obj[key].toString();
            }
            titles<<gm9title;
            ui->listWidget->addItem(gm9title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [errores](https://i.imgur.com/OLgJyHZ.png)

Comment: Disculpa, hice modificaciones y no me di cuenta si funcionaban, ahora ya los corregi, pruebalo y comentame como te fue.

Comment: funciona!!!!!!!!!!